# printf stops working halfway through my function

Tags: c

my code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void confab(const char* inText, int nRows, char* outText) 
{
    int inText_length = 0;

    printf("inText 1 = %c\n\n", *inText);
    for (; *inText != '\0'; inText_length++){
        printf("%d %c\n", inText_length, *inText);
        inText++;
    }
    for (int z = inText_length; inText_length > 1; z--){
        inText--;
    }
    printf("inText 2 = %c\n\n", *inText);
    printf("This line doesn't print");
}


int main(void)
{
    char buffer[60] = {'\0'};
    char* s = "Don't wait until the last day before starting.";
    confab(s, 3, buffer);
    //printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is keep inText a constant and get the length of the input string used in the main function. (I'll then do more things using that length later) So what I've done is start two for loops to get the length of inText by incrementing it, then decrementing it so it's back in its original state.

But for whatever reason the last two printf functions aren't showing up.
Also, I can't use the line

```
inText - inText_length;
```

for whatever reason, it says the line doesn't do anything, so I've tried to replace it with the second for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to add a `\n`, else it doesn't flush the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at this line:

```
for (int z = inText_length; inText_length > 1; z--){
    inText--;
}
```

I think what you mean is this:

```
for (int z = inText_length; z > 1; z--){
    inText--;
}
```

Instead of using

```
inText - inText_length;
```

you should use

```
inText = inText - inText_length;
```

or

```
 inText -= inText_length
```

Comment: I am not sure what you actually want to do. I read completely trough the code and found immediately this mistake. If you want us to help you better you should really write down literally what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: I'll do it in 2minutes, it's making me wait that long for whatever reason.

If you don't mind, could you also tell me why

inText - inText_length;

isn't acceptable?

Comment: @Matthias I don't want to achieve anything, but as I am seeing this for loop, I think it does nothing else than subtracting `inText_length` from `inText`.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I do not exactly get the purpose of the whole function. It looks a bit over complicated to me. But probably the code is not yet finished inside this loop or someone wanted to look at it with the debugger. I do not know.

Comment: @Matthias then you haven't read the question properly, as it states: "Also, I can't use the line `inText - inText_length;` so I've tried to replace it with the second for loop" ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you not using [strlen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) ?
You have an infinite loop in you function, indeed:

```
 for (int z = inText_length; inText_length > 1; z--){
    inText--;
 }
```

You're decrementing z but using `inText_length` in the condition, here is the fix:

```
 for (int z = inText_length; z > 1; z--){
    inText--;
 }
```

Is you don't want to use strlen, you should at least use another pointer to avoid the second loop:

```
char* ptr = inText;
for (; *ptr!= '\0'; inText_length++){
    printf("%d %c\n", inText_length, *ptr);
    ptr++;
}
```